# R - alternatives to install_github for paths over 100 bytes?

Tags: r, github, installation, devtools

I'm trying to install the Metabox R package from Github, using the following code:

```
devtools::install_github("kwanjeeraw/metabox")
```

However, I'm getting the error message:

```
"Warning in utils::tar(filepath, pkgname, compression = compression, compression_level = 9L,  :
     storing paths of more than 100 bytes is not portable:
     ‘metabox/data/two way repeated ANOVA/mx 69088_HepG2 cells_Hirahatake & Meissen_high fructose_summer course_08-2015_submit.xlsx’"
```

It looks like the issue is that the path names for some files in the repository are longer than the 100 byte limit imposed by R. Are there alternatives to install_github() for getting around this issue? I know I can download the Github repository as a .zip file, but I can't figure out how to then install it in R.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Clone it as a normal .git directory, then use devtools::install()?

Comment: Well I feel silly, I assumed I needed a workaround so different that it didn't even occur to me devtools might already have the function I needed. I just used install_local() on the .zip file and it worked. Thanks!